# angular 8 prod mode import then catch throws compiler not found error

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-cli-v8

java spring 5, Angular 8+ with Cli 8+

I have lazy lazy load enable for modules which looks as following and works perfectly fine build with or without --prod flag

```
{
  path: 'abc'
  loadChildren: () => import('abc.module').then(m => m.abcModule )
}
```

If server session is expired module loading just blows up and won't do any thing so i added `catch` block after `then` as following which builds fine in both with or without prod mode, but with prod mode build when i click on route `abc` in browser gets following error.

```
{
      path: 'abc'
      loadChildren: () => import('abc.module').then(m => m.abcModule )
                          .catch( () => window.location.reload() )

    }


Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
Error Runtime compiler is not loaded
at Xi.Gi(main-es2015.50abc434343..js)
```

i am scratching my head not sure about this, can some one help ?

Comment: can you confirm the path for 'abc.module'. Would './abc.module' also work? You might specify "./abc.module" (or whatever the relative to root path to your module is.)

Comment: yes it is prefix ./

Comment: Can you share your angular.json file. you can just include the build configurations, mostly interested in prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved after i upgraded angular and cli version to 9.